# map a special character from a font to a compose key shortcut

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, fonts, ibus

I am trying to figure out what are the feasible ways to type in non-english using the 
standard us keyboard.

So far I have figured out how to set the compose key and use 
key shortcut: 
for example

```
compose key + ` + e = é
```

Now I want to customize the key combination to a specific character from a specific font
How do I go about doing that? Also, does a font come with predefined key combination?

Also, is this something ibus input selector can help? If so, any links would be helpful. 
I have looked quite a bit on this now and have not able to figure out a working approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can't map a key to a special character in a font. Input doesn't know anything about font, only characters. Most characters are present in Unicode, and you can set a compose combination to any Unicode character. In `~/.XCompose`, you can either put the character in quotes or write the hexadecimal code for the character with `U` before it:

```
<Multi_key> <acute> <e> = U00E9
```

If you want a keyboard shortcut to insert a character in a different font, you'll need to do it in the word processor. Most programs work with text and don't even have a concept of mixing fonts.